# Export excel into sqlserver using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SSIS package to export excel data to sqlserver database. In which i am success and i am able to insert the data into sqlserver table. For that i used following steps.
1. Added Excel source
2. Data Conversion layer
3. OLEDB destination

And when i run the package i am able to insert the data. Now my requirement is if any change is done with in excel and when we re-run the SSIS package the database must updated instead of trying to insert as it give error because of primary key. I have tired the following way,
With in the OLEDB destination configuration i selected the sqlcommand option instead of Table view from the dropdown and in the command box i added the following query

```
Insert into unicode(ID
      ,Description
      ,Start_Date
      ,End_Date
      ,Start_of_week
      ,Is_Shift_allowed
      ,Any_other_info) Select ID
      ,Description
      ,Start_Date
      ,End_Date
      ,Start_of_week
      ,Is_Shift_allowed
      ,Any_other_info FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Files\backup\MasterList.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES','SELECT * FROM [Project$]')
```

when i click on parse query it shows exception as sysnatx erroe "),". 
Any suggession are welcome!..
Thank you
Sangita
    'SELECT * FROM [Project$]')

Comment: What kind of change you are doing it in your `Excel` ?. If the `metadata` changes in `excel` ,then probably ur method wont work

Comment: One of the column in excel is project end date. If the end date is changed then the data must be updated in sql databse using the project id.

Comment: You can use `Lookup` transformation for the `Project id` and if there is a match then `Split` transformation for the `Project End Date ` to see whether the column has changed or not .If changed use `OLEDB command` to update . Check this link out http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/09/12/SSIS_3A00_-Checking-if-a-row-exists-and-if-it-does_2C00_-has-it-changed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pre-loading table in which every time the etl is started, it will be first truncated (use sql taks) and then filled with the excel data. After that add another sql taks and write a merge statement (insert/update) using the column EndDate.